# Parsing date time strings with C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime, model-binding

I understand that if you want to parse a dateTime String in a specific format when converting it to a DateTime object you do this

```
DateTime someDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(myDateTime , "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

However when using a model binding with MVC C# the code is declared like this

```
public DateTime someDateTime {get; set;}
```

When doing this how do you set the format which incoming date string are expected to have?

Comment: Do you *absolutely* have to do this? I'd expect the model binding to be in a machine-readable format, typicaly ISO-8601. Is there any reason you'd need something else here?

Comment: I though ISO-8601 is a standard for setting the format
not a fixed format.

ie you could set yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm
or
yy-m-D hh:MM:ss
or countless other variations

Comment: No, ISO-8601 is a specific format. (There are variants, such as whether it's 20190321T205500 or 2019-03-21T20:55:00 for example.) But "yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm" is *not* ISO-8601

Comment: are you saying that i can assume that the DateTime object in the MVC model-property binding will expect ISO-8601 by default and i need to make sure what i am submitting is in that format?

Comment: That's what I'd *expect*, and it's definitely worth trying first. That's the most reasonable, standardized format to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a separate property for having the formatted version of the date:

```
public DateTime someDateTime { get; set; }

public DateTime someDateTimeFormatted {
    get {
        DateTime.ParseExact(someDateTime, "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
}
```

If the date you're trying to serialize will not naturally serialize into a datetime you can write a custom serialization for it of you can pass it in the request as a string and parse it in a getter of a diff model property similar to what `someDateTimeFormatted` is doing above

Comment: I thought that display attribute way only set the default display format.
can it also be used to set the parse format?

Comment: if using

get {
        DateTime.ParseExact(someDateTime, "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }

surely i would be using set (not get)

Comment: @megaman it only needs a getter and acts on the value of the non-formatted property which is the one that has the set... ive edited my answer to try and make this more clear